# Preserve text input value in jQuery Mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, back-button, textinput

I have some found some stange behaviour in jQuery Mobile that I can even repoduce on the demo website:

1. go **directly** to http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/textinputs/
2. enter something in a text input
3. click any link on the page and enjoy the ajax-y animation
4. go back using the browser's back button

**Result**: The text entered in the text input is still there. This is what I want.

However, this breaks if you come from somewhere on the site:

1. go to http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/
2. klick on "Text inputs"
3. do steps 2 to 4 from above

**Result**: The text entered in the text input has disappeared. This is not what I want.

I tested this on Chrome for Desktop and the Windows Phone emulator, both show the same behavior. What can I do to always preserve the text entered in the text input? In my case this is a search box. I want the user to be able to refine the search terms after navigating back from the search results without having to enter everything again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because, when you come from docs/forms, ajax is disabled at the beginning. So, then, jQueryMobile disable dom-cache. You can force dom cache by adding this before your loading jquerymobile.js :

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
});
```

**Edit** :

My solution works, i just tried it :

- Go on [my demo page](http://labs.julien.guyomard.org/stackoverflow/10297911/solution/forms.html) ;
- Click on "Text inputs"
- Enter something in "Text Input:"
- Click on "Search input" on the left side (just some links works in my demo)
- Go back using the browser's back button

Your text is still there !

(Note : This [page](http://labs.julien.guyomard.org/stackoverflow/10297911/problem/forms.html) show the originale version, with the problem, and so without domCache, to prove that i didnt change anything else when i duplicate jQueryMobile-Docs Pages to do my demo).

Comment: Wow! This works just fine, thanks! You'll get the bounty in 16 hours. :)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this, it saved the life of many people.

```
 $.extend(  $.mobile , {
        ajaxEnabled      : false,
        hashListeningEnabled: false
    });
```

Can read much on the following link.

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-true-browser-back-button-issue

Comment: This does not solve the problem at all. In fact it causes it to *always* forget the entered text.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way I found is to store your data in a local storage using pagebeforehide  and put it back when needed using pagebeforeshow